# change domain laravel not working properly

Tags: php, laravel

after i change my domain name... laravel is not working properly i cant login and register with no error... when i login redirect where middleware is set... even on register are same... on my previous domain name all are working with no problem...

I already try change  'domain' => 'pctiannge.com',in config/session

try to composer dump-autoload, composer update, clear laravel cache and config still no luck...

I try different broswer all are same output...

i can navigate my website...

Comment: [pctiangge](https://pctiangge.com) my website

Comment: what laravel version are you using? there's no `url` config inside `config/session`, did you mean `config/app`?

Comment: php artisan config:cache after changing config files

Comment: im using laravel 5.1 sorry     'domain' => 'pctiannge.com',
 @aceraven777

Comment: What session driver are you using?

Comment: @aceraven777 file

Comment: Maybe you forgot to change some configurations in your `.env` file. Or check your `storage\logs` to find out what's happening.

Comment: there is no new error when i login or register... my logs are empty

Comment: @JuanCarloF.Yarra, maybe your `storage` folder is not writtable, try running `chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170936/discussion-between-aceraven777-and-juan-carlo-f-yarra).

Answer (score 1):

When changing anything in any of the config files or the .env you should always run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

This will clear your current cache and cache your new settings.